# How to configure NGINX location to serve Codeigniter RESTful API in sub directory of server?

Tags: linux, nginx, php, php-fpm, codeigniter

I have the following directory structure:

```
mysite.com
- /api (codeigniter RESTful API Server)
- /app (backbonejs app)
```

I'm trying to configure NGINX to point all requests for mysite.com/api* to the api directory and use Codeigniter's setup.

Everything i've found works fine, if CI is in the root directory. But, the moment you try to put it in a sub-directory, it fails.

This is what I currently have:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name local.mysite.com;
        root /Users/me/Sites/mysite;
        autoindex on;
        index index.html index.php;

        location /api {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /api/index.php;

            location ~ \.php$ {
                root /Users/me/Sites/mysite/api;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
            }


        }



    }
```

Doing this just gives me a 'File not found' error. Not even a proper nginx 404. How do I configure NGINX for CodeIgniter in a subdir of a server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who is trying to figure this out, and failing because no answer is out there yet, here is a super simple setup:

```
140     server {
141         listen 80;
142         server_name local.mysite.com;
143         root /Users/me/Sites/mysite;
144         autoindex on;
145         index index.html index.php;
146
147         location /api {
148             try_files $uri $uri/ /api/index.php$args;
149
150         }
151
152         location ~ \.php$ {
153             fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
154             fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
155             include fastcgi_params;
156         }
157
158
159
160     }
```